# Running apps with ARM native code on x86 Oreo emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can't test my app on Android Oreo emulator because only x86 emulator is available for this API level, and my app has armeabi-v7a native code. It seems that the x86 emulator is lacking libhoudini because attempt to launch the app fails with the `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error.

Short of compiling the native code for x86, is there a way to run my app on the Android 8 (Oreo) emulator?